# Perform a page break within \cvlistitem in moderncv template

Tags: lists, page-breaking, moderncv

I am using following template

```
\cvlistitem{

\begin{itemize}

\item 1

\item 2

\item 3

\item 4

\item 5

\item 6

\end{itemize}}
```

Currently, if it is not able to fit in same-page, it take whole thing to next page. I want a page break between 3 and 4. How can I put a page break here?

Comment: You could complete your minimal working example (MWE) so that it compiles? You should add a `\documentclass{<some class name that includes "cv", presumably>}` and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and as little else as is necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I am using \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}